# Randomeading Nodejs telegraph json

Tags: telegraf

using a telegraph button I coded with nodejs, I want it to send the names available in the json randomly to the user whenever I press the button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could shuffle your json object whenever your button is pressed. And the previous message gets deleted.
This would be done like this:

```
bot.action('callback_data', (ctx) => {
     ctx.deleteMessage()
     var json
     // Shuffle json

     ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, `${json}`, {
        reply_markup: {
           inline_keyboard: [
               [{text: "Settle", callback_data: "callback_data"}]
           ]
        }
    })
})
```